# The admod can't show in real device

Tags: flutter, admob

I use the [firebase_admob 0.8.0+3](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob) for show admob in my app, it's working in testing mode, but when I deploy to my real device, it doesn't work, there is on ad to show in android device, and I just got below error in console:

```
W/flutter (11675): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/Ads     (11675): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (11675): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

but when I try to add the testDevices, and it can show the ad with `Test Ad` label

another way in iOS, it can show the Ad in my iPhone 8+, but can't show in other iOS devices, I just doubt why and how can I fix it?

Please find below code:

```
FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
    MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
        keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
        contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
        birthday: DateTime.now(),
        childDirected: false
        // testDevices: <String>[
        //   'FBBACD1EFD1C957AEF3087B3C9074B8F'
        // ], // Android emulators are considered test devices
        );

    myBanner = BannerAd(
      // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
      adUnitId: appUnitId,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event is $event");
      },
    );
```

Should I need to publish to google play to let it works?!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just for reference, when I publish the app to app store and google play store, the ad function is working, so that's realy need to publish the app for the admod for works!

Answer (score 0):

The error can occur if you have just created the adUnit Id in admob. So, you need to wait for sometime(up to a day) to get fills.

Comment: actually, I have wait for a few days :(

Comment: Try it with a VPN. Sometimes it takes times for the ads to propagate to all countries. Also check the blocking controls to see if you have blocked ads.

Comment: I also doubt that the network issue, but I tried to use difference network also failed, and if that's network issue, why it works fine in my iphone?

Comment: The ad networks may take time to propagate to all devices and countries. So, you may get ads if you choose a VPN or use a different device.

Comment: I tried to use VPN for a few countries but still not working, just show the same error, but my iOS devices are ok, that's strange !

Comment: Have you tried other Android devices to see if the issue is with the platform? Your fill rate also depends on the device and the advertising id connected to the device.

Comment: I just tried to another android device and is same:(